# How do I deal with async for a response in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I'm using [this](https://github.com/nufyoot/createsend-node) package as an API wrapper to interact with the CampaignMonitor API within a serverless function. The objective is to return a response to the caller of the serverless function, confirming whether the operation of adding a subscriber to CampaignMonitor was successful or not.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

  // set request details
  const listId = process.env.CM_LIST_ID;
  const details = body;

  // Send Request and check for error returned
  api.subscribers.addSubscriber(listId, details, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: err }),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'success' }),
      };
    }
  });
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, I think due to the fact that there is no await for the response to the final part where the request is sent. I'm a little unsure of how to handle it, with it being a callback function.

I've been playing with this code for a little while now and, if there is no error, the subscriber is added to the subscriber list and a success response is returned from the serverless function when the second return statement is outside of the callback (below api.subscribers.addSubscriber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Returning a value from the callback function of `api.subscribers.addSubscriber` doesn't make it a return value of the wrapper `handler` function.

**Solution**

As the library you are using doesn't provide a promise-based API, you can create a promise wrapper around it and use that to get the desired result.

Easiest way to create a promise wrapper around something in nodeJS is to use the built-in `util` module.

```
const util = require("util");

const promisifedAddSubscriber = util.promisify(api.subscribers.addSubscriber);
```

Once you have a promise-based `api.subscribers.addSubscriber` function, you can `await` the call to this function.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    ...

    // explicitly bind "this"
    const result = await promisifedAddSubscriber.bind(api.subscribers)(listId, details);
  
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'success' }),
    };
  }
  catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: error }),
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm still running into an issue with this, I'm getting an error now "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at 'node_modules/createsend-node/lib/interface/subscribers.js:12:20"

Seems to be something to do with createsend-node API wrapper?

Comment: This is probably because of incrorrect value of this. Try to explicitly bind the value of this: `await promisifedAddSubscriber.bind(api.subscribers)(listId, details)`

Comment: Still not working I'm afraid. I'm getting errors returned for valid inputs, it's also not giving me the detailed error message that I was getting in the callback function previously (i.e.: email address already exists in list)

When I console log the error from the catch, I'm getting the same 'Cannot read property 'post' of undefined'

Comment: Issue is definitely because of [incorrect value of this](https://github.com/nufyoot/createsend-node/blob/13129f097968c8d15e607374b65969443963c8fc/lib/interface/subscribers.js#L11). Have you tried binding `this` like shown in the above comment? Could you edit your question to include the updated code?

Comment: Yes I've pasted the whole try catch block you added above, and replaced the code after 'const result =' with your above comment

Comment: Nevermind, I've retried this and it's now working. Thanks!!

Comment: Better to include the `...` preamble inside the `try {}` block. That way, if the preamble was to throw, the error would be caught and handled in the same way as a `promisifedAddSubscriber()` error. As it stands, the function's caller(s) need to handle a preamble error.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 agreed.

Answer (score 0):

find working implementation of async-await below:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try
  {
      const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

      // set request details
      const listId = process.env.CM_LIST_ID;
      const details = body;
    
      const result = await api.subscribers.addSubscriber(listId, details);
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'success' }),
      };
  }
  catch(err){
      return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: err }),
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this doesn't work though. I'm getting the error 'callback is not a function', presumably because the callback is required but is missing from this version of the code

Comment: in that case, make the correction in addSubscriber function. Now issue is in that function. can u send that piece of  code

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `check_saved_url`. Inside of the Promise, you then need to use `resolve` to replace `return`. You can also use `reject(new Error("error"))` if there was an error.

You can read more about promises on [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

```js
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

        // set request details
        const listId = process.env.CM_LIST_ID;
        const details = body;

        // Send Request and check for error returned
        api.subscribers.addSubscriber(listId, details, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(new Error({
                  statusCode: 400,
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: err
                  })
                }));
              } else {
                resolve({
                  statusCode: 200,
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'success'
                  })
                });
              }
            });
        });
    };
```